# The correct way to update props with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

What is the correct way to remove and add a source/layers with Mapbox? I am using React, and have issues and get an error when a the source `data` prop is updated. As far as I have read in the documentation of Mapbox `removeSource` should remove it before adding it again, but it is not working on a component update.

> Error: There is already a source with this ID

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map(config);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const map = this.map;
    map.remove();
    map.removeControl(Draw, 'top-left');
  }


  shouldComponentUpdate(props, nextProps) {
    const { data } = props;
    if (JSON.stringify(data) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.data)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (JSON.stringify(data) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.data)) {
      this.fetchMap();
    }
  }

  fetchMap() {
        const map = this.map;
        const { data } = this.props;
        map.addControl(Draw, 'top-left');

        map.on("load", (e) => {
            if (data.features !== null) {

                if (map.getSource("locations")) {
                    map.removeSource("locations");
                }

                map.addSource("locations", {
                    type: "geojson",
                    data: data
                });
            }
        })
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you call `map.addSource` multiple times during your component lifecycle.

If I understood correctly, what are you trying to achieve, then you should move your map `load` event handler to the `componentDidMount` method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { data } = this.props;

  const map = new mapboxgl.Map(config);
  map.addControl(Draw, 'top-left');

  map.once("load", (e) => {
    map.addSource("locations", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: data
    });

    this.setState({ mapIsLoaded: true });
  });

  this.map = map;
}
```

Note the usage of `map.once` instead of `map.on` and setting `mapIsLoaded` state variable, after the map is done the loading.

Now you can handle your source update on `componentDidUpdate` after map is loaded:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { data } = this.props;
  const { mapIsLoaded } = this.state;

  if (!mapIsLoaded) {
    return;
  }

  if (data !== prevProps.data) {
    this.map.getSource("locations").setData(data);
  }
}
```

That's it.

---

By the way, I'm the author of [React Component Library for Mapbox GL JS](https://github.com/urbica/react-map-gl). The project is intended to be as close as possible to the Mapbox GL JS API.

For example, this is how you can rewrite your code with the library:

```
<MapGL mapStyle='mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9'>
  <Source id='locations' type='geojson' data={data} />
  <Layer
    id='locations'
    type='circle'
    source='locations'
    paint={{
      'circle-radius': 6,
      'circle-color': '#1978c8'
    }}
  />
  <Draw />
</MapGL>
```